# Proper format for SQL Server Connection String on 1and1.com

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have spent several hours trying to search this on the web in addition to calling and emailing support at 1and1.com web hosting with no success.

I have ASP.NET pages which connect to MS SQL Server database using the entity framework.  On my local machine, all works fine (naturally).  However, when I modify the connection string in my web.config to point to my SQL Server database on 1and1.com, I get the following error:

> "Unable to load the specified metadata resource."

Here's my current connection string (as defined in my web.config file):

```
    <add name="TimeDataLicenseEntities"
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/
     Model1.csdl|res://*/
     Model1.ssdl|res://*/
     Model1.msl;
     provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
     provider connection string=&quot;
     data source=dbXXXX.db.1and1.com,1433;
     Integrated Security=false;
     initial catalog=database_name;
     user id=dboXXXX;
     password=valid_password;multipleactiveresultsets=True&quot;" />
```

(Please note that where there are 'XXXX' the values are different in the actual config file as well as for 'database_name' and 'valid_password')

I'm using the Entity Framework in the code so I'd prefer solutions that correct the content of my web.config file.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to the db on 1and1 from your machine or from their server where the website is deployed?

Comment: I'm attempting to connect to the database from the website deployed on their server using the entity framework.

Comment: It's about the meta data (csdl etc.), [this](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/08/13/38628/) may help you.

Comment: @GertArnold - that was key.  I found that by following the lead provided on the link I was able to correct some errors in my web.config file. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Would you mind sharing the corrected connection string as an answer? (It's OK to answer your own question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what ended up working for me:

```
<add name="TimeDataLicenseEntities"
 providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
 connectionString="metadata=
 res://<assemblyname>/Model1.csdl|
 res://<assemblyname>/Model1.ssdl|
 res://<assemblyname/Model1.msl;
 provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
 provider connection string=&quot;
 data source=dbXXXX.db.1and1.com,1433;
 Integrated Security=false;
 initial catalog=database_name;
 user id=dboXXXX;
 password=valid_password;
 multipleactiveresultsets=True&quot;" />
```

By including the assemblyname for my code in the  sections above (the brackets ('<' and '>') should not be included), I was able to finally get it to work.

Thanks all for your assistance.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what actually works on 1and1 server from ASP.NET Code first design. So, simply replace your serverName, DatabaseName, UserID, and Password.

```
<add name="DefaultConnection"
     connectionString="Data Source=dbXXX.db.1and1.com,1433;Initial Catalog=dbYYYYY;Integrated Security=False;user id=dboZZZZZ;password=YOURDBPASSWORD;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Hope this can help anyone looking to use 1and1 asp.net server since their customer service is pretty useless.

Comment: Where is an answer?