# 1and1 sql server database is not working in asp.net mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

I have hosted asp.net mvc4 application in 1and1 web hosting. I am using entity framework. Previously I hosted my site in windows azure. Everything is working fine in azure.

### **My connection string is**

```
Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=dbxxxxxx.db.1and1.com,1433;
  Initial Catalog=dbxxxxxx;User Id=dbxxxxxx;Password=*****;
```

I am getting an following exception:

### **Exception**

```
{System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException: An error occurred while getting provider  information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct. ---> System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(SqlConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(SqlConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
at System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices providerServices, DbConnection connection)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices providerServices, DbConnection connection)
at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInfo(DbConnection connection, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest)
at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator()
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator()
at MigrationApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in h:\BitBucket\Production code\easamove.models\MigrationApp\Program.cs:line 18}
```

I have been fighting with this issue for the last 3 days. Any help would be great full.

Thank you

Comment: Looks like the core error is this one: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. **The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.** - Have you got all the names right?

Comment: I have added correct connection string only. And I am not able to connect 1and1 sql server through management studio also.

Comment: You might also want to check out [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20569712/33051) where the issue was in finding the csdl files correctly.

Comment: If you can't connect to the SQL instance through Management Studio, and the error's saying that it can't find or connect to the server, that would imply that your connection details are wrong. Have you contacted 1&1 for advice?

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="metadata=
          res://*/Easa.Models.csdl|
          res://*/Easa.Models.ssdl|
          res://*/Easa.Models.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
         Data Source=dbxxxxxxxxxx.db.1and1.com,1433;Initial Catalog=dbxxxxxxxxxx;User Id=dbxxxxxxxxxx;Password=dbxxxxxxxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>  keyword not supported 'metadata' error coming

Answer (score 0):

Databases have a 1GB limit. If you go over the 1GB limit, you cannot add anymore data unless you remove some.

You cannot make a connection to Microsoft SQL Server from an Enterprise Manager due to security reasons. The only means of access to your Microsoft SQL database is through ASP or ASP.net scripts that run on 1&1 Server.

[Source](https://help.1and1.com/hosting-c37630/databases-c85147/ms-sql-database-c39531/ms-sql-database-restrictions-a604349.html)